# 3 Node kafka cluster work fine with only 1 node up is it correct?

Tags: apache-kafka

Hi I have a weird situation. I have 3 node Kafka cluster. I set offsets.topic.replication.factor =3 I run producing and consuming messages and weird thing happening when I stopped 2 Kafka's. There is no problem in producing or consuming messages from Kafka. As I know there should be some kind of errors when consuming messages. Should it work with only 1 broker up? I'm using Kafka 3.4

I expected that there will be errors when consuming messages, but cluster is working fine

Comment: The errors will be on the broker side, not exposed to clients, generally.

Answer (score 0):

offsets.topic.replication.factor:

The replication factor for the offsets topic (set higher to ensure availability). Internal **topic creation will fail** until the cluster size meets this replication factor requirement.

let's look at another setting,

in.insync.replicas (set by producer):

When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), this configuration specifies **the minimum number of replicas** that must acknowledge a write for the write to be considered successful.

Generally speaking, replication.factor ensure availability when some replicas are down and producer trade-off between consistency and efficiency by adjusting in.insync.replicas.